# Quick Edit not allowing records in list to be edited

Tags: sharepoint-online, quick-edit

My SharePoint list has Quick Edit enabled. But whenever I am in Quick Edit mode, nothing in the list is editable.

The view changes like it's supposed to when you initiate a Quick Edit, but the cells cannot be edited.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Whether all lists occur the same issue? Please create a brand new list and click Quick Launch to check the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verify whether it is happening for all columns or few of them, generally in **multiline text** column this problem occurs, so if there is any multiline column, verify the below steps :

1. Access the SharePoint List
2. Click on List >> List Settings.
3. Click on the multiline text field for which you want to change the
   text format
4. Select the type of text as “**Enhanced rich text”**

For more details please click [here](https://ppmworks.com/sharepoint-list-fields-are-not-editable-in-quick-edit-view/).

Comment: That was it, Habibur. Thanks!